# CLLocationManager not updating while in background, and get messy location coordinates Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have a tracking function but it doesn't update location while in background.

1st case: Tracking while app is in the foreground -> the tracking is actually happening but doesn't get precise coordinates. I will change to `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` to see if improves accuracy of the tracking.

2nd case: Tracking while screen is off -> the tracking is a straight line from a to b, tracking doesn't update coordinates.

3rd case: Tracking while app is in back ground(pressed home button) -> tracking is happening as case 1.

I found a post that explains that if authorisation is set to always you have to specify you want to keep updating location while in background, but nothing has changed. This is the code and info.plist :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        mapView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
//        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
//        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true  //for getting user location in background mode as well

        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow   //map following user                    

        configureLocationServices()
        addDoubleTap() // enabling duble tap gesture recognizer
//        mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location!, 1000, 1000) // set mapView based on user location coordinates
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        centerMapOnLocation()

        // alerts coordinates to post to Firebase
        let alertDrawLatitude =  alertDrawCoordinates?.latitude  // not used ?
        let alertDrawLomgitude = alertDrawCoordinates?.longitude
        let title: String? = alertNotificationType
        var subtitle: String? = alertNotificationType

        //  user alert notification. takes coordinates from alertNotificationArray( populated with firebase returning coordinate for all alerts

         displayAlerts()
    }            

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else { return }        
        self.actualRouteInUseCoordinatesArray.append(mostRecentLocation.coordinate)

    }            

    func configureLocationServices() {
            if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined{
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            } else if authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true //set update location even if in background. very imposrtant!!
          }
        }
```

[image: info.plist]

UPDATE:

changing the accuracy only made things worse.

with AccuracyBest:
[image: accuracy best]

and with AccuracyBestForNAvigation

[image: accuracy best for navigation]

second tracking is actually worse.. how can navigation apps rely on this kind of tracking? is there anything wrong with my code for LocationManager?

SECOND UPDATE:
it now get updated location when in background, but is way off..I never passed the yellow street and it shows like I waked for 10 minutes after it..

THIRD EDIT:

I found out that I should filter out GPS raw data, so I'm using a Kalman filter, and it really smooths out the resulting tracking.
So I'm fine tuning two parameters, and in order to be able to change those parameters I added two textfields `@IBOutlet weak var filterValueTextField: UITextField!` and `@IBOutlet weak var horizontalAccuracyTextField: UITextField!`and connected those to the parameters

`hcKalmanFilter?.rValue = Double(String( describing:filterValueTextField?.text!))!` and `guard mostRecentLocation.horizontalAccuracy < Double(String( describing: horizontalAccuracyTextField?.text!))! else { return }`.
My problem is now that it finds nil while unwrapping value in the horizontalAccuracy parameter. 
If in horizontalAccuracy I just put a value it accepts an integer, but when I take it from the texField converting the textfield.text to Int, compiler throws an error `Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CLLocationAccuracy' (aka 'Double') and 'Int'`, while if I convert it to Double doesn't, but it finds nil.
Why the filterValue finds a value from it's textField, and the horizontal Accuracy doesn't? they're declared, and use the same way.
Any idea?

[image: traking is way off]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have limited time while your app goes to background, and that time is depend upon load on your device's OS, but most probably it is approx. 30 seconds. So this is the reason your are not getting location updates while your screen is off or while your app goes to background.

But Apple allows app to run in background for some tasks and location update is one of them, so you can fetch location updates even if your app goes to background by enabling `Background Fetch` capability for your app.

For more details please follow below official doc. of Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background

And secondly try to maintain your `locationmanager` object in global scope of your app like you can place it in `AppDelegate` or in Singleton class if you are maintaining any for your app, so it will always be available.

Comment: I see that I didn't turn on background capabilities, now my info.plist changed. Is the las line of the info.plist screenshot still needed? Also, what you mean by maintain `locationManager`in global scope? how do I put those functions in  AppDelegate instead of my mapViewVC? Thank you for the link.

Comment: Yes, last line is added by XCode when you enable Background fetch, so don't remove it. And you can maintain `locationmanager` in global scope by creating one singleton class and write all methods in that class. And this will help you to maintain `locationmamager` from any view controller.

Comment: I just tested it, it now gets updates even when scree is off. but the traded path is way out . see second update screenshot

Comment: what benefits would I have from maintaining location manager functions global? I just use it in mapVC. I'm starting so I would like to keep thing simple . That is a pattern the would easily make me loose  sight of my code. I did us it dough in another portion of my app, declaring static variables in a class apart, but I guess that all that extra typing made me want to keep it simpler as I went.  EG. `MyVariables.myVariable`it made sense there because I would point to those variables from other classes.. but with Location I thought it wasn't giving me any benefit, just extra typing.

Comment: Having a second though dough I thought of doing it for when I'd make the goglemaps version of my mapVC. so yes I'd be better off maintaining it global.
I'm just not sure of how would I put it in AppDelegate.

Comment: @ Dhavel D. Going back to the question, why is it getting those weird locations?
in info.plist the line is been added by xCode when I enabled background capabilities and thats correct, but the line UIBackgroundModes key (with the location value) was added when trying to enable background location, but as I see is for iOS 4, so I deleted it thinking that maybe it was causing some conflicts with the new line added by xCode and be the cause of the weird locations updates, but the result was that I wasn't getting background location updates again. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Line in info.plist won't do anything wrong, that is just the permission which device OS reads and allow your app to get location in background. So for inaccurate location you have to look into code only not in info.plist

Comment: I'm finding confusing infos about gps data. It seems to be dependant of if it comes from cell tower and Wi-Fi, which is non desirable, and can be not be taken into account using the vertical accuracy parameter. I didn't find how to set that value to avoid taking those into account. Using `guard mostRecentLocation.verticalAccuracy > 0 else {return}` I don't get any point onto map after the starting point.

Comment: I also found out about filtering raw gps data, I might just need some filtering as some Kalman filtering, but I found infos saying that CoreLocation already performs filtering, but looking at my tracking screenshots it doesn't seem to be true. It's so zaggy that I thought I had a bad antenna in my iPhone..

This Is runkeeper team talking about this kin of gps data related problems
https://academy.realm.io/posts/mbltdev-phillip-connaughton-runkeeper/

Comment: Can you see what's the problem in my THIRD EDIT of my question?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes location that you receive does not have desired accuracy, especially when you've just started tracking, first couple of locations are going to be well off. You can use [location's horizontal accuracy property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423599-horizontalaccuracy) to filter location witch have, for example, less then 50m accuracy

Comment: Thank for answering, I'm kinda lost here.. How would implement that? as an experiment I installed a tracking app, well it doesn't get accurate tracking eighter..

Comment: well, right after `guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else { return }` you could also check `guard mostRecentLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 50 else { return }`

Comment: Thank you,that seems to be what could make tracking usable, I was start thinking that maybe my iPhone had a broken gps antenna, which I don't discard yet. I'll test it going to work in a little while, and i'l tell you.
with the app I installed yesterday "Road Bike" I can see orientation of  map, which seems quite precise. I guess than that's using giroscope data and not gps

Comment: Can you see what's the problem in my THIRD EDIT of my question?